# Is there a way to tell ISC KEA DHCP to always broadcast answers to clients?

Tags: dhcp

I want to use ISC KEA DHCP v1.5 but I am not able to assign addresses to clients behind a wireless bridge. The reason for this is that KEA send sets the target IP address in the IP header to the offered one in the DHCP answer. To get KEA working with the clients behind the wireless bridge I need it always sending DHCPOFFER and DHCPACK by broadcast and not by unicast.
Is there an option to tell KEA to always broadcast? I have read through the whole Administration Rederence Manual but I haven't found any such option but maybe I have missed something.
If there isn't such an option I think a little hook library is the only solution.

Comment: Or patch&rebuild from the source package the distribution offers. That's what I do in those cases.

Comment: Yes, that would be a possible solution but this would require a lot of work to understand and change existing code. Adding a simple hook library would be the solution that requires less work in case that there is no existing configuration option.

Comment: In case you are interested, it's in `server/dhcp.c, dhcp_reply()`, the relevant variable is `&lease -> hardware_addr`. Replacing that by the ethernet broadcast address should work.

Comment: @Janka Thanks a lot for your amount of work but that's the source of the old ISC DHCP server (also called DHCPd). ISC KEA is a completely new DHCP solution written in C++.